# Finding derivatives to solve for the coefficients of a polynomial function

Tags: calculus

A polynomial function $f$ is defined by $f(x)= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ where $a, b, c$, and $d$ are constants. The function $f$ has a local minimum at $(4, -70)$, a local maximum at $(-2, 38)$ and a point of inflection at $(1, -16)$. Find the values of $a, b, c$ and $d$.

So I solved for the first derivative $f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx+c$.
Then I solved for the 2nd derivative, $f"(x) = 6ax + 2b$.

Plugging in the max and the min $x$ values into the first derivative and setting $= 0$ I get
$48a + 8b + c = 0$
$12a - 4b + c = 0$

Plugging in the inflection point $x$ value into $f"(x)$ will result with
$6a + 2b = 0$

However, when I try solve the system it fails. Is it because the first two equation are parallel?

Well then to solve this system I would need another equation. However, the only other equations that I can derive involve plugging any points into the original function. Since this would now introduce another unknown, $d$, it looks like I'd actually need $2$ more equations?

Am I missing an easier way to solve this. This is for a Calculus $1$ course.

Comment: Your formula for the first derivative is not accurate. It is missing a term.

Answer (score 1):

You have derived all of the relevant information that comes from knowing the $x$ coordinates of the turning and inflection points. As you've noted, this does not give you enough information to completely resolve the system.

However, you have been given more information about those key points than just their $x$ values, and if you include this then you should have enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean just plugging the (x, y ) coordinates of the given points into the original equations - I'd generate 2 more equations with a,b,c and ds, then eilimate the d by combining? If so, that is what I was thinking or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: to expand, I'd plug in (-2, 38) and (1, -16) into f(x) and generate 2 more equations. Or am I missing another method?

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do. In total you'll have about 6 equations, but you've already found one redundancy and I'm guessing there's one more in there somewhere.